# Why dont my facebook interstitial ads show in my app?

Tags: swift, xcode, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

Im in Swift and every-time I call them the delegate func didFailWithError gets called. Im using the same code I use for the facebook intersitial ads in all my apps and it works perfectly except for this new app I created. No ads pop up and I get a message in my console saying:

> DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file:
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4E5FA239-208C-4B08-87C6-E4DB1CC3CC76/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies

This is how I setup the code in my GameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let interstitialFBAD: FBInterstitialAd = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "2320559454634478_1321860725967683")

class GameViewController: UIViewController, FBInterstitialAdDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

        loadFBInterstitialAd()

    }
}

//fbAds--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func loadFBInterstitialAd() {
    interstitialFBAD.delegate = self
    interstitialFBAD.load()
    print("what")
}


func interstitialAdDidLoad(_ interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd) {
    interstitialFBAD.show(fromRootViewController: self)
    print("popup")
}

func interstitialAd(_ interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("failed")
}

//fbAds--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you setup the plist keys correctly? Is that a new placement ID? There's really too many reasons as to why it might not be working. We need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from

> Im in Swift and every-time I call them the delegate func didFailWithError gets called. Im using the same code I use for the facebook intersitial ads in all my apps and it works perfectly except for this new app I created. No ads pop up and I get a message in my console saying:

This seems like my first solution is not the answer, but it's so obvious I need to point it out nonetheless: from the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) it seems like there's a couple steps to creating an app that can use the SDK properly (namely creating an app in Facebook and using the proper `Info.plist` keys, etc).

If that's not what is happening, though, which I imagine it's not, then this could still be due to the application not being properly set up but for a reason other than Facebook SDK.

Without seeing how you are initializing the SDK in your `AppDelegate` and without confirmation it's not `Info.plist` keys that are missing for the ads you are attempting to show, it's hard to say what the issue could be here. Have you contacted Facebook support? They'd definitely be able to help here as well. Somewhere off [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios-interstitial) I'm sure you can find proper live support as a paying ads customer.

Comment: Its not the info.plist because I checked it with my other apps and its setup the same way.